# Find all subfolders of folder by name n levels deep

Tags: debian

I want to find all the snapshots on a cephfs filesystem.  They are represented as a directory under the hidden `.snap` directory, and lazily loaded when reading/writing to the snap.

So I want to find all folders that exist in a `.snap` folder, only searching for `.snap` folders n levels deep.

What would be the command for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ find /path -mindepth n -type d -name '*.snap'
```

- `mindepth` tells `find` to only start searching for matches *n* levels deep from the specified path (in this example, `/path`) for matches
- `type d` tells `find` you're interested in matches which are directories only
- `name *.snap` is self-explanatory, but tells `find` you're interested in matches which nave names ending in `.snap` only